# External Display Image Looks Much Better @60Hz Than @120Hz

Tags: macos, mac, display, bug

I recently bought a Mac Studio and have been using the Samsung CRG9 external monitor that supports up to 5120 X 1440 at 120Hz, but for some reason, I've noticed that the image on the display looks much brighter, vibrant, and sharper when using 60Hz instead of 120Hz at the same 5120 X 1440 resolution. It almost looks like there's a grey/tannish overlay on the display after switching from 60Hz to 120Hz. Is there anyway to fix this other than reverting to 60Hz all the time? Not sure why there's such a noticeable difference in the display quality between the different refresh rates. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your display (is it going into a different mode for high-refresh rate)?

Comment: What cable and port are you using to connect the display?

Comment: Using a Thunderbolt 3 to DisplayPort 1.4 cable. Doesn’t appear that the screen is switching modes when using the different refresh rate, that’s what I figured was happening too but after messing with the settings on the display it doesn’t seem like there’s anything changing between refresh rates. Really weird.